# Measure the execution time of a function call in Perl

Tags: perl, time

Is it possible to execute staff only if the previous function is not over yet and the time is over
Something like:

```
my $timeout = 10; # seconds
sub get_entities {
    # do staff ...
}
get_entities();

if (time == $timeout and get_entities is not over yet) {
    # do staff...
}
```

Comment: Unix or Windows?

Comment: The system is Unix

Comment: There's no way in a single threaded program that get_entities() will not be done by the time you get to the next statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit made the question considerably more complicated.

As I'm sure you'll know - as a standard, perl runs sequentially - if a command takes 25s, then the rest of the code just waits until it's ready.

But sometimes, you want to build in a timeout yourself for various reasons. There's a number of ways you can do this:

**`alarm` and a signal handler**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

$SIG{'ALRM'} = \&handle_alarm; 

my $we_are_snoozing = 1;

sub handle_alarm {

   print "Caught SIGALRM\n";
   $we_are_snoozing = 0;
}

sub have_a_snooze {
   while ( $we_are_snoozing ) {
       print "Zzzz\n";
       sleep 10;
   }
}


alarm 25;
have_a_snooze;
print "Done\n";
```

You're limited in what you can do inside your handler - keep it minimal. But `alarm` generates a `SIGALRM` (which can also be generated by `kill`) and the process can trap and handle it.

**`threads`**

Threads allow you to spin off part of your code to run in parallel or asynchronously. This is handy for both resource usage, but also when you're faced with a thing that's not worth waiting indefinitely for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use threads; 
use threads::shared;

my $we_are_snoozing : shared;
$we_are_snoozing = 1; 

sub have_a_snooze {
   while ( $we_are_snoozing ) {
       print "Zzzz\n";
       sleep 10;
   }
}


my $thr = threads -> create (\&have_a_snooze);

sleep 5;

if ($thr -> is_joinable) { 
   print "Thread exited normally\n";
   $thr -> join;
 }
 else {
    print "Thread still running, detaching it\n"; 
    $we_are_snoozing = 0;
    $thr -> detach;
}
```

**`IO::Socket` and `can_read`**

One of the more common reasons for wanting a timeout, is simply waiting for IO.

This is quite easy to handle with `IO::Socket` and a timeout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = open ( my $input, '-|', "some_command" );
my $select = IO::Select -> new ( $input ); 
while ( $select -> can_read(10) ) { 
  my $line = <$input>;
  print $line; 
}
```

This will timeout 10s after the *last* result, not the first. But that may be useful too.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
my $start = time;
get_entities();
my $duration = time - $start;
```

Or were you looking for something more sophisticated?

Comment: If you are looking for 'more sophisticated' - `alarm` and a signal handler could be the answer.

Comment: @Dave Cross It is more more sophisticated, I edited my question, to give you an idea I'm working on a webhook

Comment: Also, Time::HiRes may be useful if more granular timing is needed.